# Python and Redis. Why is scan_iter() so much slower than keys() with mget()?

Tags: python, redis

I made a script to compare query speeds between methods in the redis library.

As I understand it, I should not use redis.keys() because it's a blocking function. The preferred method is scan_iter(), which doesn't block. That makes sense. But I don't understand why scan_iter is so terribly slow.

This script uses three techniques to query a redis database.

1. Use redis.keys() to get all of the keys. Use redis.mget() to get all the values.
2. Use a for loop with redis.scan_iter and redis.get() to get the values. (Note I don't need keys, just values)
3. Use redis.scan_iter() to get all of the keys. Use redis.mget() to get all the values.

Option 1 was by far the fastest. Option 2 was 20 to 30 times slower. Option 3 averaged 4 times slower.

Why is this? Have I written my code incorectly? Do I have the wrong method? Is the redis.keys() method actually the best choice?

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep
import redis
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='192.168.3.16', port=6379, decode_responses=True, db= 0)

def query_keys():
    start = datetime.now()
    redis_keys = r.keys(pattern='*')
    redis_keys = [x for x in redis_keys if not x.startswith('1_')]
    values = r.mget(redis_keys)
    end = datetime.now()
    print(str(len(values)) + ' values queried in ' + str(end - start) + ' with keys and mget.')
    
def query_scaniter():
    start = datetime.now()
    values = []
    for s in r.scan_iter():
        if not s.startswith('1_'):
            values.append(r.get(s))
    end = datetime.now()
    print(str(len(values)) + ' values queried in ' + str(end - start) + ' with scan_iter.')
    
def query_scaniter_mget():
    start = datetime.now()
    redis_keys = []
    for s in r.scan_iter():
        if not s.startswith('1_'):
            redis_keys.append(s)
    values = r.mget(redis_keys)
    end = datetime.now()
    print(str(len(values)) + ' values queried in ' + str(end - start) + ' with scan_iter and mget.')

for i in range(3):
    query_keys()
    query_scaniter()
    query_scaniter_mget()
    print('\n')
    sleep(5)

Output:
3532 values queried in 0:00:00.046872 with keys and mget.
3532 values queried in 0:00:00.781314 with scan_iter.
3532 values queried in 0:00:00.109385 with scan_iter and mget.


3526 values queried in 0:00:00.031245 with keys and mget.
3522 values queried in 0:00:00.812616 with scan_iter.
3522 values queried in 0:00:00.125007 with scan_iter and mget.


3529 values queried in 0:00:00.031246 with keys and mget.
3531 values queried in 0:00:00.797011 with scan_iter.
3530 values queried in 0:00:00.109357 with scan_iter and mget.
```

Answer (score 7):

Those results are as expected.

The reason to avoid `KEYS` isn't that it's slow, it's that it blocks the server, preventing it from satisfying other client requests. By contrast, `SCAN` only returns a few results at a time, allowing the server to stay responsive to all clients.

The tradeoff is that doing a lot of `SCAN` calls imposes extra overhead (including the network overhead of all those round-trips). So the total time for your client will be longer, but you won't cripple the server, which is generally a more important consideration.

Note that you can have the same issue with `MGET` if you have a huge number of keys. The most *scalable* solution (which is different from the *fastest*) would be to get a few keys at a time with `SCAN`, and then `MGET` those keys.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone still needing an answer, use the following:
redis.scan_iter(match="STRING*MATCH*PATTERN", count=10000)

count=10000 allows 10k keys to be returned at a time, significately reducing network back & forth.  You can change this value.